# How to include blade tempate in another file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have two fiels:

```
landing.blade.php
```

And block `comments.blade.php`.

How can I include comments.blade.php inside `landing.blade.php`?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include one blade template into other by following syntax:

Including Sub-Views

```
@include('view.name')
```

You may also pass an array of data to the included view:

```
@include('view.name', array('some'=>'data'))
```

For more details you can follow:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views) you need to `@include` it:

landing.blade.php:

```
<div>
    Some content

    @include('comments', ['comments' => $comments])
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

simple way,

if `landing.blade.php` and `comments.blade.php` are on the same directory, let's assume they are both on `ressource/view`

So on `landing.blade.php` you can write `@include('comments')`